# Unable to find Interface in C# using reflection with Name.EndsWith

Tags: c#, reflection, ildasm

The name of interface is **IService**, but when I am trying to find the Interface in reflection in C#, it is not able to find because due to some reason the Interface name changes to **Iservice'1**

Please have a look to attached screenshot for Ildasm :

[image]

Actual Interface is like

```
 public interface IService<TOutput> 
        where TOutput : class, new()
    {
        Task<List<TOutput>> GetAllAsync(dynamic inputParameter);
    }
```

Code to find Interface:
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Services"))
           .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))

Here it fails to find Service, as IService is having some different name then defined one.

**Any Idea why the name looks this way and how to resolve it ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IService` is a generic.  In other words, it's `IService<T>`.  When compiling to MSIL, C# generics have their name modified as you noticed.

You could make the service non-generic, or use `.Contains` instead of `.EndsWith`.

Comment: Any post where you have came across this ?

Comment: I don't have a documentation link handy, but you can easily verify this yourself with reflection.  `typeof(List<int>).Name == "List\`1"`

Comment: @Dreamweaver You can even see in your screenshot that the name is `IService`1`. This is btw a hack by the compiler, if i recall correctly, to allow classes with the same name and different amount of generic parameters. The reasons are outlined in Serge Lidins IL Assembler book.